# Why access token does not contain all permissions after updating Office 365 application permissions in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I registered multi tenant Office 365 application in Azure AD admin center and configured required permissions that this application asks for. Also I created web service that uses this application.

My web service had been working for half a year and at some point I extended functionality of my web service and now it requires several new permissions. Also I realized that some permissions are not required for my web service any more.

So I added extra permissions and removed those that I don't need in Azure AD, saved the permissions and clicked "Grant permissions" button.

[image]

In my web service I perform [re-authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) in order to update access token for working with created Office 365 application and use extra permissions. But when I get access token using my web service and decoded the token on this site I don't see that extra permissions were provisioned. Also I see that my web service gets token with those permissions granted that I removed from my application. So even after re-authentication user from another tenant that use my web service gets token with "old" permissions set.

Why so? How can I provision all the application permissions I previously set up for my Office 365 application in Azure AD to the tenant that uses my service? I just need the permission set in the token be up to date with those I configured in Azure AD.

Comment: If your app is multi-tenant you will need to go through the consent process again in all tenants that your your application. `Grant permissions` button as you show from Azure Portal will only take care of consent and updating permissions for the Azure AD tenant to which application belongs itself.. for all other Azure AD Tenants, you will need to do consent again separately for the changed permissions to take effect..

Comment: Could you please clarify how can I go through the consent process in tenants that use my application? Could you provide a link to documentation where I can find consent flow described?

Comment: Take a look at the consent framework documentation here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework for general understanding.. and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin specifically for Admin Consent Endpoint.. Here is a sample url from the docs `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions`